# Can't uninstall trial version of Expression Blend 3, error writing to file Config.msi

Tags: windows, uninstall, windows-installer, microsoft-expression

I can not remove a trial version of MS Expression Blend 3 from my pc. I am always getting the same error: "Error writing to C:\Config.msi\6e6288.rbf." The name of the file varies. On the error message window there are two buttons: "Retry" and "Cancel", but clicking on any of them gives the same result - uninstall is cancelled and everything is rolling back.

I tried to change access permissions to that folder in many ways, but result all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to uninstall it with the help of [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) program.